# How to add a js context menu design to my vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs3

I have a vue3 project that has a pretty standard context menu in a list view and since vue accepts js code. I am wondering if I could implement this pie context menu in my vue project and how should i do it?

Pie context menu:
https://github.com/cevherkarakoc/Pie-Context-Menu

I tried downloading the js and css file and stored it in the /assets folder and imported the files but i don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: The repo that you have linked is quite outdated and not maintained anymore. I was going to suggest [those](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#context-menu) but they somehow face the same issue. I guess that you could still one of them for a quick Vue prototype but the best approach would be to do something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom Vue wrapper component to any other JS library.

Check the links:

- [How and Why to Use Wrapper Components in Vue 3](https://learnvue.co/tutorials/vue-wrapper-components)
- [Vue component wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305185/2487565)
- [Vue2 Wrapper Component Example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html?redirect=true)